Use Reorder from framer-motion with useArrayFields from react-hook-form
I'm creating an app with ReactJS and I found a problem using the Reorder components of framer-motion with the useArrayFields from react-hook-form.
In fact, the Reorder component change the order of a list with a setter, however, the fields variable of react-hook doesn't have any setter to change the order of it self but instead has functions like append, prepend and insert (i believe) to add values according to the order we want.
The problem then is, how to link both.
I tried many thing and came up with a pretty poor result.
I, first of all, tried to reorder the field list by recreating it each time the onReorder activates.
I quieckly found that the list was reorder each time we moved one of the items of one slot. Which is pretty normal because the onReorder method just activated.
Then, I tried the same thing but with, this time, an dragStart and dragEnd event on the itmes the selves. This didn't worked either.
At the end, I tried the same thing but with an addEventListener and a useEffect or react but I had a worse result cause the list woundn't change at all.
Here is my code:
The principal file :
import React from 'react';

import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useForm, useFieldArray } from "react-hook-form";

import Axios from 'axios';

import { Reorder } from "framer-motion";

import POS_line from "./assets/POS_line";


const POSSettings = (props) => {
    const toast = props.toast;

    // Use State
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [settingNameDisplayed, setSettingNameDisplayed] = useState("default");

    const [isDragging, setIsDragging] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleWindowMouseMove = event => {
            setIsDragging(true);
        };

        window.addEventListener('mousedown', handleWindowMouseMove);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleWindowMouseMove);
            setIsDragging(false);
        };
    }, []);

    const handleDragStart = () => {
        setIsDragging(true);
    };

    const handleDragEnd = () => {
        setIsDragging(false);
    };

    const handleReorder = (newOrder) => {
        if (!isDragging) {
            remove();
            newOrder.forEach((item, index) => {
                append({name: item.name, isOpen: item.isOpen, services: item.services})
            })
        }
    };

    const { 
        register,
        control,
        formState: { },
        setValue,
        getValues,
    } = useForm();

    const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray({
        control,
        name: "pos"
    });

    const [posList, setPosList] = useState(fields);

    useEffect(() => setPosList(fields), [fields]);


    useEffect(() => {
        // Load data
        const loadData = () => {
            setIsLoading(true);
            Axios.post("http://localhost:3726/api/posSettings/getByName", {name: "default", getData: true, getMeta: false})
            .then((res) => {
                if (res.data === "failed") return toast("error", "An error occured while trying to loading data... Please retry or contact an administrator.");
                console.info("POS Settings successfuly loaded");

                const pos = res.data[0].pos.split(',');
                const open = res.data[0].open.split(',');
                const services = res.data[0].services.split(',');

                for (var i = 0; i < pos.length; i++) {
                    append({name: pos[i], isOpen: open[i] == "true", services: services[i]});
                }
                setPosList([...fields]);

                setIsLoading(false);
            });
        }

        loadData();
        
    }, [settingNameDisplayed]);

    console.log("Pos list:", posList, "\nFields:", fields);

    return (
        <>
            <div className="flex-row-around settings-box__header">
                <h4>POS Settings</h4>
                <select onChange={(e) => setSettingNameDisplayed(e.target.value)}>
                    <option value="default">Default</option>
                    <option value="none">None</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div className="flex-col-around settings-box__content">
                <div className="pos__section">
                    <Reorder.Group 
                        values={fields}
                        onReorder={(newOrder) => {
                            remove();
                            newOrder.forEach((item, index) => {
                                append({name: item.name, isOpen: item.isOpen, services: item.services})
                            })
                        }}
                        axis="y"
                    >
                        {fields.map((item, index) => ( 
                            <POS_line 
                                key={item.id}
                                item={item}
                                index={index}
                                handleDragStart={handleDragStart}
                                handleDragEnd={handleDragEnd}

                                register={register}
                                setValue={setValue}
                                control={control}
                            />
                        ))}
                    </Reorder.Group>
                    <div className="flex-row">
                        <button onClick={() => {}}>Add POS</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="general__section">
                    <input type="number" name="groupSize" min="1" pattern="[0-9]+" id="test"/>
                </div>

                <div className="flex-col apply-ettings__section">
                    <label>
                        Always activated
                        <input type="radio" name="periodActivation" value="always"/>
                        <span className="radio-custom"></span>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        Periodicaly activated
                        <input type="radio" name="periodActivation" value="period"/>
                        <span className="radio-custom"></span>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        Activated only one day
                        <input type="radio" name="periodActivation" value="day"/>
                        <span className="radio-custom"></span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default POSSettings;

The aux file where we have the items :
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';

import { Reorder, useDragControls } from "framer-motion";

const POS_line = (props) => {
    const register = props.register;
    const setValue = props.setValue;
    const control = props.control;

    const controls = useDragControls();
    const [isFocused, setISFocused] = useState(false);

    const item = props.item;
    const index = props.index;
    const handleDragStart = props.handleDragStart;
    const handleDragEnd = props.handleDragEnd;

    return (
        <Reorder.Item 
            value={item}
            id={item}
            dragListener={false}
            dragControls={controls}
        >   
            <div className="flex-row pos__line">
                <svg
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    width="16"
                    height="16"
                    fill="#ACACAC"
                    viewBox="0 0 16 16" 
                    // onDragStart={handleDragStart} 
                    // onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}
                    onPointerDown={(e) => controls.start(e)}
                >
                    <path d="M1 4a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v2a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1zm5 0a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v2a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H7a1 1 0 0 1-1-1zm5 0a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v2a1 1 0 0 1-1 1h-2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1zM1 9a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v2a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1zm5 0a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v2a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H7a1 1 0 0 1-1-1zm5 0a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v2a1 1 0 0 1-1 1h-2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1z"/>
                </svg>
                <div className="flex-row-between" style={{width: "100%"}}>
                    <div className="flex-row">
                        <label>
                            <input 
                                type="checkbox" 
                                {...register(`pos.${index}.isOpen`, {required: true})} 
                            />
                            <span className="checkbox-custom"></span>
                        </label>
                        <input
                            type="text" 
                            placeholder={"POS n° " + index}
                            {...register(`pos.${index}.name`, {required: true})}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button>
                            <img src="pictures/three-dots.svg" alt="" title="Modify the POS services' hours" style={{verticalAlign: "middle", paddingRight: "10px"}}/>
                            Modify
                        </button>
                        <button onClick={(e) => {}} style={{width: "50px", background: "#FAFAFA"}}>
                            <img src="pictures/trash.svg" alt="" title="Delete the POS" style={{verticalAlign: "middle", filter: "contrast(0) brightness(.25)"}}/>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Reorder.Item>
    );
}

export default POS_line;


I'm sorry, I can't give you a minimum reproducible example but only this code.
Here are the versions of y dependencies :
"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.6.8",
    "framer-motion": "^11.0.24",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^5.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.51.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
  }


useFieldArray returns a replace function that you can use to replace the array. Have you tried that?

Well, it's a bit less laggy but the same problem occurs, the drag stops at the first position where it should be replaced..., but thank's a lot, it's already much better !!!

Calculate the difference between the old list and the new list and then apply a swap:
 const { fields, append, remove, swap } = useFieldArray(
    {
      control: form.control,
      name: "yourArray",
    },
  );

  function reorderList(newFields: typeof fields) {
    // Find the first index where the order differs
    const firstDiffIndex = fields.findIndex(
      (field, index) => field.id !== newFields[index].id,
    );
    if (firstDiffIndex !== -1) {
      // Find the new index of the item that was moved
      const newIndex = newFields.findIndex(
        (field) => field.id === fields[firstDiffIndex].id,
      );
      // Swap the items
      swap(firstDiffIndex, newIndex);
    }
  }

<Reorder.Group
  values={fields}
  onReorder={reorderList}
>

